# FileLocatorPro API not able to fire off event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am using the FileLocatorPro SDK for some searches I need to do... I have set up the handler for an event but the event never fires so I'm curious to make sure I'm doing this right!

*Enviornment*
- Visual Studio 2015 RC
- C#
- using FLProCoreLib.dll in project

*My C# Class*

```
public class SearchManager
{
  public SearchEngineClass mySearchEngine;
  public bool IsComplete;

  public SearchManager()
  {
     this.mySearchEngine = new SearchEngineClass();
     this.mySearchEngine.OnSearchFinish += mySearchEngine_OnSearchFinish; //this was autocomplete by VS after typing the "+=" and hitting tab twice...
     this.IsComplete = false;
  }

  public void mySearchEngine_OnSearchFinish()
  {
      this.IsComplete = true;
  }

  public void RunSearch()
  {
     mySearchEngine.Start(true); // true makes it run asynchronously. I've also tried setting to *false* but that doesn't fire off the event either...
  }
```

Q1: This is how you should be able to define an event handler in code correct?
Q1b: Has anyone encountered this with FileLocatorPro and how'd u resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://help.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/sdk/searchengine_class.htm) you need to setup some search criteria before you do the search.

The VB code example they give looks like this:

```
engineSearch = New SearchEngineClass

engineSearch.SearchCriteria.FileName         = "*.txt"
engineSearch.SearchCriteria.ContainingText   = "search"
engineSearch.SearchCriteria.LookIn           = "c:\search folder"
engineSearch.SearchCriteria.ContentsExprType = ExpressionType.RegExpClassic
engineSearch.SearchConfiguration.SearchThreadCount = 1

Dim listResult As SearchResultItemList = engineSearch.Start( False )
```

Your event looks like it is declared correctly.